# Get windows file informations like the comment of a msi file

Tags: node.js

How can I get file informations from an `.msi` file like the comment?

I don't seem to get them via fs module `fs.stats`.

Answer (score 2):

To read windows files metadata you can use the [get-file-properties](https://github.com/Jack-Barry/get-file-properties) package that is a wrapper around the [wmic command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc784966(v=ws.10)).

From the doc:

```
import { getFileProperties, WmicDataObject } from 'get-file-properties'

async function demo() {
  // Ensure you are using double backslashes in your file path
  const filepath: string = 'C:\\path\\to-my\\file.txt'
  let metadata: WmicDataObject

  metadata = await getFileProperties(filepath)
  console.log(metadata.FileSize)
}
```